# Appium is not able to locate the element on Side Menu of app in iOS simulator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to click on the below 7 elements displayed under the UIATableView element but apppium is not able to find these with the given xpath.

[Below is the appium inspector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU6eG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by using name. Try this and it should work:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@name='xID Settings' and @index='0']");
```

Comment: @gaurav- I have tried this but still its not able to find by name.

Comment: or can u try to take snapshot by UIAutomator and give it to me?

Comment: @gaurav- the locator given by you is still not located

Comment: i told you to share snapshot from UI automator. This way i can't say anything why its not working.